# Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft Office Excel<br/>

Tags: php

I am facing this problem.

my file  abc.php is

```
<?php 
 ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 300);

$filename = "d:\abhi.xlsx";

$sheet1 = 4;

$arr=array(1=>'a','b','c','d');

$excel_app = new COM("Excel.application") or Die ("Did not connect");
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok this solved it for me

if you’ve got IIS configured try this:

- Run “dcomcnfg” to get to Component Services
- Open Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Search for Microsoft Excel Application or the appropriate application you working with on COM
- Right-Click on it and open the properties
- Choose “Identity” tab
- Normally this is set to “the launching user” by default. You have to change this to “the interactive user”.
- Apply these new settings and test your COM application. It should work fine now.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Answer (score 0):

Change that from `Excel.application` to `Excel.Application`

Answer (score 0):

Create folder **Desktop**

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Right click folder **Desktop** -> properties -> Security -> Add permission user to Full control